# How to view large comments in spreadsheet properly in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

I have got a spreadsheet which has some very large comments in some cells. The last part of these comments is not properly visible as in the screenshot.

[image]

How can I read the text in the comment properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to increase the width of the comment box; obviously, it isn't a matter of text length but of the heigth of the comment box.

Depending on your needs (and the content of the comment), you may put the comment's content in a writer file and replace the current comment content by a hyperlink to that file, or insert the odt file as OLE object into the comment.